# Excel - Working with incremental numbers, series (summing, finding values, etc)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-lambda

#### Context / Example

I am working with some datasets that have *incrementing numbers¹*. For example, I mean where the cost of an upgrade gets more and more expensive for each level you go up.

| Level | Cost |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 550 |
| 5 | 650 |
| 6 | 750 |
| 7 | 850 |
| 8 | 950 |
| 9 | 1050 |

We can describe the cost formula for **a single upgrade** as `Cost = 150 + ([Level] * 100)`, however I am struggling a bit when trying to work out values over ranges (i.e. summing the cumulative cost of multiple upgrades)...

---

#### 1️⃣ Summing Cost

| Input/Output | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Current Level: | 4 |
| Desired Level: | 7 |
| **TOTAL COST:** | **???** |

How do I work out the total cost of doing multiple upgrades -- e.g. in this case, going from level 4 to 7 would cost a total of `550 + 650 + 750 = 1950`

**Please can you provide the Excel formula for this type of calculation**

---

#### 2️⃣ Finding a value

| Input/Output | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Current Level: | 4 |
| Units Available: | 1,500 |
| **NUM UPGRADES:** | **???** |
| **NEEDED FOR NEXT LEVEL:** | **???** |

Another thing I have been asked to work out is essentially the inverse... i.e. given a starting point/level, at what point does the cumulative cost exceed the number of units available.

In this case, `Num upgrades = 2  |  1500 > 1200 (550 + 650)`
and `Needed for next level = 450  |  750 - (1500 - 1200)`

**Please can you provide the Excel formulas for these two types of calculations**

---

¹ If there is a better term for 'incrementing numbers' please let me know and am happy to revise the question.

**LAMBDA TAG:** I believe this may involve the *lambda* function, so have added that tag to this post. If this is not right, please let me know and I can remove the tag.

Comment: If desired level is `7` then it should be 4,5,6,7 `550+650+750+850`?

Comment: To clarify, the cost is what it takes to complete the given level, so think of 4 as more "4 --> 5".

Comment: The `lambda` function and `Lambda Calculus` are not the same. Replaced with correct tag.

Comment: Why not just get the [Amulet of Zenithar](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Specialty_Gear#Amulet_of_Zenithar) then `Prices are 10% better` so you can level of faster. :)

Comment: `If there is a better term for 'incrementing numbers' ` - [Recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option:

[image]

Formula in `B3`:

```
=SUM(SEQUENCE(B2-B1,,B1)*100+150)
```

Formula in `E3`:

```
=LET(z,SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(E2/150,,E1),LAMBDA(a,b,a+b*100+150)),y,XMATCH(E2,z,-1),VSTACK(y,ABS(((E1+y)*100+150)-INDEX(z,y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For you r first problem `FILTER()` may work.

```
=SUM(FILTER(B2:B7,(A2:A7>=E2)*(A2:A7<E3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I take with this approach I would need to create an interim table to `FILTER`?... I did consider that however I was reluctant to go down this road as (1) I am expecting to have many different models by the end (so Cost2, Cost3, Cost 3B, etc) and also (2) I don't know the max level, so there could be tens or hundreds of rows needed... I suppose for now, this might have to be 'Plan B'(?)